# How can I read a CSV file as a rake task and instantiate a model class? - getting ActiveRecord connection error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, connection, rake

I am writing a Ruby on Rails application which has a Rake task that can parse a CSV file.

Here is the code:

```
 desc "Import Channels into DB\n Usage: rake channel_import"
 task :import_channels, :path_to_channel_list do |t, args|

 require "#{Rails.root}/app/models/channel"
 require "csv"
 filePath = args.path_to_channel_list
 puts "Filepath received = #{filePath}"
csv = CSV.read("#{filePath}", :encoding => 'windows-1251:utf-8')
  csv.each_with_index do |row, i|
 if [0].include?(i)
      puts "Skipping over row #{i}"
      next
     end
     if(row.nil?)
      puts "row[#{i}] was nil"
     else
channelName = nil
      classif = nil
      owner = nil
      channelName = row[0].force_encoding('UTF-8')
      classif = row[1].force_encoding('UTF-8')
      owner = row[2].force_encoding('UTF-8') 
      if (channelName.nil?)
        puts "Channel name for row #{i} was nil"
        #add entry to Log file or errors database
        next #skip this row of the csv file and go to next row
      else
        channel_hash = Hash.new("name" =>"#{channelName}", "classification" => "#{classif}", "owner" => "#{owner}" )

      end
       puts "\nChannel Name = #{channelName}\nClassification = #{classif}\n Ownership = #{owner}"
      #If channel name exists in the Database, update it
      xisting_channel = nil
      xisting_channel = Channel.find_by channel_name: '#{channelName}'
      if(xisting_channel.nil?)
          #create a new channel
      @new_channel = Channel.create(channel_hash) 
      puts "Inserted....#{@new_channel.inspect}"
      else
          #update existing channel
          Channel.update(xisting_channel.id, :classification => "#{classif}", :ownership => "#{owner}" )
          puts "Updated...."
          puts "channel_hash = #{channel_hash.inspect} "
      end#end if/else

  end#end if/else

 end #end CSV.each


 end
```

When I run this code I get the following error message:

```
 MRMIOMP0903:am AM$ rake import_channels[/XXXXXXXX/Channellist.csv]
 Filepath received = /XXXXXXX/Channellist.csv
 Skipping over row 0

 Channel Name = APTN HD+
 Classification = Specialty
 Ownership = Aboriginal Peoples Television Network
 rake aborted!
 ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

I tried to create a Channel object using IRB and it worked just fine. The DB is created and I'm seeing it using MySQL WorkBench. All tables are there, however, I am unable to create the Channel object from the Rake task.

My hypothesis is, perhaps outside of a certain folder/hierarchy the app cannot access the ActiveRecord::Base class or something like this.

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

UPDATE:

---

BAsed on the answer by Phillip Hallstrom

I changed the top line to load the environment

```
 task   :import_channels => :environment do|t, args|
```

Then tried rake import_channels and got this error:

```
rake aborted!
undefined method `safe_constantize' for #<Hash:0x007fbeacd89920>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the environment prior to running your Rake task. I'm not familiar with your multiple task name options there, but for a simple example, you'd want this:

```
task : import_channels => :environment do
```

Comment: You dropped ":path_to_channel_list".  Is that where safe_constantize is being defined?  You probably need to work that task back into the mix.